# Generate variable amount of variables within a function

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building a CMS and I've written a few functions to handle some sql tasks that pop up in my script a lot. The functions are as follows:

```
function execute_sql_query($stmt,$types,$var1,$query_success,$object_name,$sql_action)
{
    if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $var1))
    {
        if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
        {
            echo 'MySQL Execution Error: ' . $object_name . '<br>';
            $query_success = FALSE;
            echo "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $object_name . ' successfully ' . $sql_action . '<br>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'MySQL Bind Error: ' . $object_name . '<br>';
        $query_success = FALSE;
    }
}

function sql_close($stmt,$query_success,$mysqli)
{
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    if ($query_success)
    {
        echo 'All changes were successfully saved!<br>';
        mysqli_commit($mysqli);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No changes were made to the database because of detected errors<br>!'
        mysqli_rollback($mysqli);
    }
}
```

The code is called as follows in the script:

```
mysqli_autocommit($mysqli, FALSE);
$query_success = TRUE;
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "DELETE FROM galleries WHERE gal_num = ?" ))
{
    $types = 's';
    $object_name = "Galleries";
    $sql_action = "deleted";
    execute_sql_query($stmt,$types,$gal_del,$query_success,$object_name,$sql_action);
}
sql_close($stmt,$query_success,$mysqli);
```

Now this works as It's supposed to and it saves me a heck of a lot of typing. I'm just having one single issue wit this type of approach.

In this query there's only a single parameter being bound. Some will alter 3, 5 or even 12 different fields in the database table. The way I've written this function it can handle only one. If a query handles more than that, I would have to write another function for each one that binds a different amount of parameters. That mainly copy and paste work but it kind of negates the usefulness of putting this in a function.

when it comes to the type, this is simply a string, so if a query binds 5 parameters, I can simply give it

```
$type = 'sssss';
```

Not a problem. I haven't found out how I can do this for the variables that will be bound. Is there a way that I can somehow feed my function a scope or array of variables (function within the function perhaps?) that will generate them automatically so I can keep all of these queries within a single function?

Say if I need to bind 3 parameters. I feed it something like the following:

```
$types = 'sss';
$bind_vars = 3;
```

And within the function it would generate:

```
if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, $var1, $var2, $var3))
```

Can this be done? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: deleted my former answer because it was totally misunderstood of my part.
So an array is still the right approach, just do it like this:

```
$type = "isssi"; 
$param = array("5", "File Description", "File Title", "Original Name", time()); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO file_detail (file_id, file_description, file_title, file_original_name, file_upload_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

$sql_stmt = mysqli_prepare ($sql_link, $sql); 
call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge (array($sql_stmt, $type), $param); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql_stmt);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I had been playing around with arrays very similar to this solution but couldn't seem to make that work. My issue is the //do something part. :)As far as I understand it mysqli_stmt_bind_param() is a built-in function that binds the parameters contained within the variables given. If I supply an array of the values that need to be bound, how the heck do I tell it to bind them correctly in the foreach() loop?

Comment: i think I completely misunderstood you, I will try to edit my answer as to get something valuable to you.